# Unable to instantiate VelocityEngine, when deploying war file

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat6, velocity, java-war

I am deploying an application on Tomcat 6, using a war file.  I've compiled the source code given by the vendor on the same machine, then moved the war file to {tomcat-home}/webapps/

When I start up the application, I see a error message:

```
The SystemInformationService could not be retrieved from the container. Therefore very limited information is available in this error report. 
The SystemInformationService could not be retrieved due to the following error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Spring Application context has not been set
Cause
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate VelocityEngine!
    at com.opensymphony.webwork.views.velocity.VelocityManager.newVelocityEngine(VelocityManager.java:333)

Stack Trace:[hide]

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate VelocityEngine!
 at com.opensymphony.webwork.views.velocity.VelocityManager.newVelocityEngine(VelocityManager.java:333)
 at com.opensymphony.webwork.views.velocity.VelocityManager.init(VelocityManager.java:146)
 at com.opensymphony.webwork.dispatcher.VelocityResult.doExecute(VelocityResult.java:61)
```

I followed the same steps on another machine and it installed correctly.

I don't understand what the error is telling me.

Could I be missing jar files? ( but it compiled fine ).

Have I forgotten to set environment variables?

I'm not sure what to make of this, I don't know what the VelocityEngine is, or does.

Comment: I found that when I changed server.xml to contain unpackWARs="true", now it works correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be because of Velocity's logging trying to log to a read-only folder, or even to the jar file.

```
* create a file "velocity.properties" and place it in the WEB-INF/classes folder.
* Inside the file, write

runtime.log.logsystem.class=org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.NullLogSystem
```

(see [here](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/im-trying-to-run-the-example-in-the-tutorial-on-tomcat-and-it-cant-instantiate-the-velocityengine.html) for original post)

Comment: The strange thing is I have deployed this as an unexploded WAR file on Jboss and it worked correctly.  I needed to unpack the WAR in Tomcat in order for this to work.